# I am getting this error when executing mpjboot on machines

Tags: mpj-express

i set MPJ_HOME in the environment variable and when i execute mpjboot machines i get this error

```
Error: MPJ_HOME environment variable not set!!!
```

`java.lang.Exception: MPJ_HOME environment variable not set!!!`

```
at runtime.daemon.MPJDaemon.<init>(MPJDaemon.java:87)



at runtime.daemon.MPJDaemon.main(MPJDaemon.java:252)

[server] Unable to start MPJ Express daemon
```

Comment: Is the issue resolved, Can you please share? Because, I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPJDaemon class is executed on compute nodes, it listens for the requests from mpirun module (running on head machine)

Please make sure that MPJ_HOME variable is set in all compute nodes you listed in machines file

Comment: 'compute nodes' in the sense what? My machines file include two IP addresses, first one is the IP address of head node from where `mpjboot machines` command is issued, and second IP address is of the machine where exactly the same configuration of mpj is done. But I am still getting the error `MPJ_HOME variable isn't set!!!` despite being already set correctly in .bashrc on both the machines.

Comment: if you are using ubuntu, try writing the export MPJ_HOME statements on the top of your bashrc