# Error while Running MPJExpress in cluster mode(niodev)

Tags: java, mpj-express

Well I know [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28055999/1612078) is the similar question. However, no satisfactory answer is provided yet.

MPJ is working just fine on multicore platform.
But, when I tried running it on cluster using niodev mode(I exactly followed the mpjexpress user guide), I got this error while starting daemon using `mpjboot machines`.

```
MPJ_HOME environment variable is not set!!!
Unable to start MPJ Express daemon
```

Despite that, I have correctly set `MPJ_HOME` and `PATH` variable in `.bashrc`.
And my `machines` file include

```
172.50.88.19
172.50.88.18
```

where first IP address is of the machine from where I am running the command `mpjboot machines` , and second IP address is of the machine where exactly the same setup & configuration of MPJ is done.

[Note: Both machines are accessible to each other over network, tested using `ping` and `passwordless SSH`]
Whats the problem ? Please help.

Comment: see following post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556289/mpjboot-bash-java-command-not-found) here